# A SharePoint page that shows all the lists on a site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, site

Is there a way to show all the list on a site?  Basically like the Site Content page except with only lists (in other words a customized Site Content Page).

Comment: you can create a custom solution using SharePoint REST API or JSOM to fetch the lists and show it on custom site page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using a Content Search web part in a custom page.

Edit page and insert a Content Search web part:
[image]

Then add the web part and click "change Query" button in the left pane. Click "Switch to Advanced Mode" in the Basic Tab, then type the text in the Query text box:

```
path:"http://sp"  (contentclass:STS_List AND contentclass<>STS_List_DocumentLibrary)
```

Besides, since STS_List including document libraries, picture libraries and other libraries, you can add “AND contentclass<>STS_List_XXX” behind the text based on your libraries.

Here is a refer: [SharePoint Power Searching Using ContentClass](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/)

If it’s not feasible for you, you can use rest API to retrieve all lists in SharePoint, here is a post for your reference: [Retrieve All Lists And/or Libraries in SharePoint Using REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/retrieve-all-listslibrary-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api/)